# custom mailchimp form using HTTP API

Tags: php, plugin-development, ajax, newsletter

I have a simple `<input type="email">` that I want to use to create a subscription form for mailchimp newsletter. I will use the HTTP API and no plugin, this because I think this will be less overkill for the app. I have only two minor question about this implementation:

1) I need to pass to my plugin or function file the `wp_ajax_nopriv` and `wp_ajax_` actions as normally I do with forms to manage the data right?

2) How I can manage the unsubscribe action from the user? I need to setup a link or something similar that will rely on a dedicated url qith action as param?

Comment: I guess you're using the Mailchimp API to subscribe and unsubscribe users? Why not just use their UIs?

Comment: I see you mentioned the ancient admin AJAX API, but I'm unsure why. You shouldn't use that API to handle form requests, and you should use the modern REST API for AJAX requests. If you've been using admin AJAX to submit forms in the past you should stop doing that. Keep in mind that the ins and outs of using the MailChimp API are not in scope of this stack, and that you'll get more answers by asking 1 question per question rather than bundling it all into a single question

Comment: Using the API just for a sign up form seems overkill. Mailchimp gives you the HTML for a form that will work without any additional work. Why not just use that?

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes, I'm still using `wp_ajax_`, this because I didn't know how to use REST API to manage form submission at the moment. If you post a link to docs and examples I will appreciate.

Comment: @Rup you have right, I just wanna do some practices with wp api and have a full customized solution in my bs4 theme, this is why. But I will consider this option.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I will consider this option.

Comment: You shouldn't use the AJAX endpoint, or the REST API to handle form submissions, to handle a form submission you should set your `action=""` so it submits it to the same page, then handle the form based on the `$_GET` or `$_POST` values. I'd recommend looking up some of the questions people have asked on how to do it

Comment: @TomJNowell what you write sounds strange, a lot of people use AJAX to handle forms submission or the standard `admin-post` method that will reload the page. maybe you for `action` mean the hidden input field?